# `labels.shape` must equal `logits.shape` except for the last dimension. Received: labels.shape=(19,) and logits.shape=(1, 19)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras, cleverhans

I am using FGSM attack using cleverhans. My code is as follows:

```
logits_model = tf.keras.Model(model_1.input, model_1.layers[-1].output)
target_label = tf.one_hot(3, depth=19)
adv_sample = fast_gradient_method.fast_gradient_method(logits_model, x, eps = 0.9, norm = 2, y = target_label, targeted = True)
```

I am getting this error

```
loss = loss_fn(labels=y, logits=model_fn(x))

   ValueError: `labels.shape` must equal `logits.shape` except for the last dimension. Received: labels.shape=(19,) and logits.shape=(1, 19)
```

I reshaped my targeted_label using
target_label = np.reshape(target_label, (1, 19)), got this error

```
ValueError: `labels.shape.rank` must equal `logits.shape.rank - 1`. Received: labels.shape=(1, 19) of rank 2 and logits.shape=(1, 19) of rank 2
```

I reshaped my targeted_label using

```
target_label = np.reshape(target_label, (1, 19)), got this error

ValueError: `labels.shape.rank` must equal `logits.shape.rank - 1`. Received: labels.shape=(1, 19) of rank 2 and logits.shape=(1, 19) of rank 2
```

Comment: Hi @gogotech, There is difference between dataset labels shape and the model output shape which is causing this error. Please provide the standalone code along with model definition code to replicate the error and fix the issue.